# Getting 'IO Error: No Such file or directory' when using string input to loop through multiple files in Python?

Tags: python, loops, csv, io

I'm just using the basic csv module to try and read in multiple files in Python. I've used this approach before where I loop through different values and input those as part of a different file name string in each loop. For some reason I'm getting the error saying /home/rwakefield/soil_anom2/%s.csv does not exist. For some reason it isn't recognizing the string input that I am trying to use, which should result in a file path looking like: "/home/rwakefield/soil_anom2/25_31_by_255_266.csv"

This wasn't a problem when I wrote the files using the same approach. It has just been an issue trying to retrieve information from the files. Is there a better way to loop through multiple csv files and read in their data? All of mine are structured with a numerical sequence to the titles so I figured looping would work.

```
import netCDF4 as nc
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
import csv as csv


for m in range(25, 49, 6):
    lat_min=float(m)
    lat_max=float(m+5.999)
    lat_max_string=lat_min+6
    lat_min2_string=int(m)
    lat_max2_string=int(lat_max_string)

    for n in range (-105,-72,11):
        lon_min=float(n+.0001)
        lon_max=float(n+11)

        lon_min_string=n+360
        lon_max_string=lon_max+360
        lon_min2_string=int(n+360)
        lon_max2_string=int(lon_max+360)

        filestring_float=str(lat_min)+'_'+str(lat_max_string)+'_by_'+str(lon_min_string)+'_'+str(lon_max_string)+'_TC'
        filestring_int=str(lat_min2_string)+'_'+str(lat_max2_string)+'_by_'+str(lon_min2_string)+'_'+str(lon_max2_string)

        for i in range (1954,2015):

            year=str(i)

            for j in range (1,13):
                month=str(j)
                MO=[]
                YR=[]
                MO.append(int(month))
                YR.append(int(year))
                TC=[]
                SA=[]
                MEAN=[] 
                mean=[]
                Y=[]
                f=open('home/rwakefield/COOK/soil_anom2/%s.csv') %(filestring_int,)

                f2=open('/home/rwakefield/COOK/tor_count/%s.csv') %(filestring_float,)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not formatting your strings properly. The parentheses are telling you how the grouping is being parsed: the string with the literal `'%s'` is being passed to `open()`, and after that happens, you then `%` it by a `tuple`. Instead, the replacement variables need to be inside the parentheses with the string they're being placed into:

```
f=open('home/rwakefield/COOK/soil_anom2/%s.csv' % filestring_int)
f2=open('/home/rwakefield/COOK/tor_count/%s.csv' % filestring_float)
```

You can also use the newer-style string formatting:

```
f=open('home/rwakefield/COOK/soil_anom2/{}.csv'.format(filestring_int))
f2=open('/home/rwakefield/COOK/tor_count/{}.csv'.format(filestring_float))
```